# doc/docx to PDF converter

Tags: php, linux, pdf

I'm running Centos Linux on my dedicated server.  I want to convert all .doc and .docx files to PDF. I have tried the API of PHPLIVEDOCX, but now I want to have application in my own dedicated server to convert them.

Is there any way I can do this either using PHP or any other tool available in Linux?

Comment: Try [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=word+doc+to+pdf), let us know how you get on! This is a very popular question here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the scripting/macro capabilities in openoffice to accomplish this. Take a look at their forums (Use a clever google search)

Or maybe this could be worth  a try? http://sourceforge.net/projects/ooconvert/

Then simply run the CLI command with a shell_exec call or similar.

Comment: Do you think i can install openoffice on my dedicated server with command line interface only?

Comment: Yes you can. Take a look at ooconvert, it should be a CLI only tool... That way you don't have to write your own converter macros in python. I have recently used a similar method for converting HTML to docx.

Installing OO on centOS should be as easy as 
`yum install openoffice`

Comment: Can you please guide me how to install?

Comment: Its says Openoffice is required for ooconverter and i'm not able to install openoffice in my CENTOS

Comment: Why are you not able to do so? Permissions? Missing package in your package manager? Dependency errors?